# Pymysql Windows Authentication Error

Tags: python, database-connection, pymysql

I am attempting to connect to SQL Server Management Studio. My code is below and returns the error: "**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trusted'." I am using pymysql, would like to connect using Windows Authentication, and am running on 64 bit windows machine. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - removed trusted. Error I am now receiving is 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

```
import pymysql
import pymysql.cursors

conn = pymysql.connect(host = 'DESKTOP-6CIMC97')
```

Comment: Just... remove `trusted = True`? And ask *how to connect using Windows Authentication?*.

Comment: I just tried this. I replaced host with 'localhost' and kept the server from above. Error displays as 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'

Comment: I am confused. Are you connecting to SQL Server (in which case pymysql would seem to be the wrong package for the purpose), or MySQL (in which case there is no Windows Auth, unless you're talking about the extension plugin in MySQL EE)?

Comment: I have a python program that needs to read values from a sql table. It executes a specific function based on those values, then runs a stored procedure within sql. I have the python code set up, the sql table set up, and the stored procedure set up, but am struggling to create the connection between python and my sql table. Based off my research, I though pymysql was what I needed. I have sql server express and use windows authentication to login.

Comment: `pymysql` is exclusively for talking to MySQL, it won't talk to MS SQL Servier. Maybe you confused `pymysql` and `pymssql`? Though actually if we're talking about using Windows Authentication then probably `pyodbc` will be an easier fit for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the example on GitHub? `trusted` doesn't seem to be required.

https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

import pymysql

conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Host,User FROM user")

print(cur.description)

print()

for row in cur:
   print(row)

cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Yes, I read this article and just tried it again. It doesn't seem to like the properties I'm sending within the conn variable. For host, I'm just copying the sql server I'm using, port I left as is (not sure where to find that), not sure about user and pword values since I'm using Windows Auth. and I put AW2014 for db since that is what I named my Adventureworks database.

Comment: Can you edit your post with the new errors by using the code above?

Comment: You need to also pass in credentials... look at the example above.

Comment: That's where I'm getting stuck. I don't have credentials. I just use windows authentication.

Comment: Perhaps you need to use another library as was mentioned above, but looking at the docs here: http://pymssql.org/en/latest/faq.html#cannot-connect-to-sql-server, my answer should work.